# How does the energy of non-resolved spectral lines get distributed in an FFT?

Tags: detection, fft, spectrum

For example, if my FFT has a poor resolution of 170Hz (data sequence length is small due to latency constraints) and I am trying to detect a sinusoid in the 150-250 Hz range, will this FFT be good enough?

I feel if the sinusoid is in the neighborhood of 170 Hz (150-200Hz), my frequency bin at 170Hz will show an increase in magnitude which I can use to detect. But what if a sinusoid is present at 250 Hz? Will its energy be distributed between the 170 Hz bin and the 340 Hz bin? And if so, in what proportion? (perhaps I can use a weighted sum to detect in that case)

Comment: I'd bet that sqrt(A^2 + B^2) would work

Comment: Also, do not forget the phase component. If a sinusoidal is off the center frequency of the bin, it will have a phase which keeps shifting (rotating) from one FFT window to the next. I think that by "uwrapping" the phase and analyzing it, you can get the sinusoid's frequency precisely; I just don't have practical implementation experience in the area to be able to "blindly spit out" the code.

Comment: For instance, suppose we are taking 8 windows per second, and have a 100 Hz bin, and there is a pure sinusoidal in the neighborhood of 100 Hz (with no other sinusoidal nearby that would mix up into the same bin). Suppose that the 100 Hz bin FFT value has a phase which changes by -45 degrees in each window. So over the 8 windows in one second, this accumulates to -365 degrees. So what does that suggest? The signal falls behind by one cycle every second relative to 100Hz, and so its frequency is 99 Hz.

Comment: That's great information Kaz, but thankfully I don't need the precise frequency, I just need to know if a sinusoid is there or not. So, my main worry is whether monitoring  a single bin (at 170 Hz) will be sufficient.

Comment: How the energy spreads out is determined by the window function you are applying to your data before doing the FFT. Fore more info, have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function

Comment: What are you trying to detect? Do you just want to know that the 170Hz component is there, or do you want to measure its amplitude accurately, or do you want to be able to resolve it from other, nearby frequencies?

Comment: What are you implementing this on? If you're only trying to detect the presensce of a frequency component, it would make more sense to use a Goertzel Algorithm than FFT. It's less computationally intensive, and you'll be able to get better resolution. Regardless of window, you will have spectral leakage, and with a desired range that is narrower than your bins, you don't have a prayer of getting meaningful results with an FFT.

Comment: @MattYoung, I haven't used the Goertzel algorithm, but according to Wikipedia, it just calculates individual bins of the DFT. OP said his data sequence length is limited by latency concerns, so I'm not clear how Goertzel can improve the resolution --- if it can do that, you should add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As The Photon says, how the energy spreads is out is determined by the window function you use. Here's an excerpt from [The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to
Digital Signal Processing](http://www.dspguide.com/ch9/1.htm), [chapter 9](http://www.dspguide.com/ch9/1.htm) (near the end):

[image: window functions]

Your choice of window function will largely depend on what about the signal you are trying to measure. Do you need high frequency resolution? Do you need accurate amplitude measurement? It's not possible to optimize for everything at once.

From your comments, it sounds like the flat-top window may be most appropriate. Again, from the guide:

> This leads us to the flat-top window, shown in Fig. 9-5d. In some applications the amplitude of a spectral peak must be measured very accurately. Since the DFT's frequency spectrum is formed from samples, there is nothing to guarantee that a sample will occur exactly at the top of a peak. More than likely, the nearest sample will be slightly off-center, giving a value lower than the true amplitude. The solution is to use a window that produces a spectral peak with a flat top, insuring that one or more of the samples will always have the correct peak value. As shown in Fig. 9-5d, the penalty for this is a very broad main lobe, resulting in poor frequency resolution.

Comment: I am expecting to see a sinusoid somewhere in the 150-250 Hz region (it can be anywhere in the range). However my fft bins are at 0, 170, 340... etc. Increasing my frequency resolution is not an option because of latency requirements that constrain data length. I just wanted to know if monitoring one frequency bin, i.e., the 170Hz one is sufficient for detection. I don't need accurate amplitude measurement, only detection of sinusoid using threshold type decision rule.The question is if my sinusoid is at 250 Hz, how much of the energy will be apparent in the 170 Hz bin;I don't want to miss it.

Comment: @ankit sounds like you want the flat-top window, then. See edits.